# WHERE clause for filtering by condition on any element of a JSONB array?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

In PostgreSQL, using a `JSONB` column, I can store arrays of values. In a `WHERE` clause, I can then filter these arrays by performing comparisons on individual array items.

As an example, I can check *"Is the first item of array `data`, cast to a number, greater than 5?"* by using `WHERE CAST((data -> 0) AS FLOAT) > 5`.

What I would like to be able to do, is to check *"Is **any** item of array `data`, cast to to a number, greater than 5?"*.

Is there a way to do this as part of an PostgreSQL query, as opposed to first fetching all data and then manually performing this filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements_text(),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) example:

```
with my_table (id, data) as (
values 
    (1, '[1,2,3]'::jsonb),
    (2, '[4,5,6]'::jsonb)
)

select *
from my_table
where exists (
    select 
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(data)
    where value::float > 5
    )

 id |   data    
----+-----------
  2 | [4, 5, 6]
(1 row)
```